# Accessing different nodes in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

**I apologize for the bad title**. I am trying to develop an XSLT file for this XML:

```
<game>
    <character>
        <name>Rambo</name>
        <attribute>
            <strength>15</strength>
            <stamina>10</stamina>
            <agility>24</agility>
            <health>100</health>
        </attribute>
    </character>

    <character>
        <name>Sonic X</name>
        <attribute>
            <strength>10</strength>
            <stamina>15</stamina>
            <agility>10</agility>
            <health>100</health>
        </attribute>
    </character>

    <costume>
        <name>Armor</name>
        <attribute>
            <agility>-15</agility>
            <health>50</health>
        </attribute>
    </costume>

    <costume>
        <name>Boots</name>
        <attribute>
            <agility>75</agility>
        </attribute>
    </costume>
</game>
```

**What my XSLT should do**: for each combination of character and costume, it needs to calculate the combined agility. E.g. (character agility) + (costume agility).

The output should look like this:

```
<boosted_agility>
    <result>
       <character> Character name (e.g. Rambo) </character>
       <costume> Costume name (e.g. Armor) </costume>
       <agility> New agility value (E.g. 24 + (-15) = 9) </agility>
    </result>
    ..........    
<boosted_agility>
```

I would like to do something like this (broken code below):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <boosted_agility> 
            <xsl:for-each select="game/character and game/costume">
                <result>
                    <character> <xsl:value-of select="character.name"/> </character>
                    <costume><xsl:value-of select="costume.name"/></costume>
                    <agility> <xsl:value-of select="costume.attribute.agility"/> + <xsl:value-of select="character.attribute.agility"/></agility>
                </result>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </boosted_agility>
    </xsl:template>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to **nest** two `xsl:for-each` instructions: one for `character` and one for `costume`. Then you'll get all combinations.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I did that but when I implemented it displayed the wrong results because I did not use variables.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would be obvious, since the inner loop is in an entirely different branch of the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @michael.hor257k said you need two `xsl:for-each`, but you'll also want to use `xsl:variable` to store your `costumes` and current `character` as it's outside of scope.

This should work :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <boosted_agility> 
        <xsl:variable name="costumes" select="game/costume"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="game/character">
            <xsl:variable name="character" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$costumes">
                <result>
                    <character><xsl:value-of select="$character/name"/></character>
                    <costume><xsl:value-of select="name"/></costume>
                    <agility><xsl:value-of select="$character/attribute/agility + attribute/agility"/></agility>
                </result>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </boosted_agility>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Nesku! It was of immense help, as I struggled for days with this. Thank you, once again!